# Are there any way to change color of part of a string?

Tags: css, colors, clip

I'am beginner at frontend, and got some design-layout to train. Designer expects that on hover part of string or even letter will change color [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ThDQ.jpg)

I thought about CSS 'clip', but doubt

Comment: Look into mix-blend-mode.

Comment: aside mix-blend-mode, there is also background-clip : example : https://jsfiddle.net/h8v3q9oj/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus yes, I think background-clip is easier to control the colors.

Answer (score 0):

I change the snippet. Play with font-size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 0);
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 50%);
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper1">Hello World!</div>
  <div class="wrapper2">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but look at the print screen, the ends of colored part may be in half of letter, for example. <Span> can't help with it

Comment: I made the change

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what the image given in the question wants (where its the color of a character that can change part way through depending on the background color).

Answer (score 0):

As G-Cyrillus has pointed out, background-clip with value text can be used, it will 'cut out' characters from the background.

In this simple snippet the background is half white, half black and the blue/white background is supplied in a pseudo before element.

Note that the property requires a -webkit- prefix in some browsers.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  rmix-blend-mode: difference;
  rcolor: white;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 0 50%, black 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello how are you?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Thanks for your help, A Haworth , G-Cyrillus! I think, I've found the solution. I experimented with `background-clip:text`, but in my case it was excess, but I used `mix-blend-mode`, thanks. I've found an article [Taming Blend Modes: `difference` and `exclusion`](https://css-tricks.com/taming-blend-modes-difference-and-exclusion/), where explained `filter:invert(1)`. Tried to show in snippet. When hover the cell part of title change color to white. But color of title and hovering background should be the same.[My realized layout from designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTmnB.png)

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  filter: invert(1);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #091C91;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  z-index: 5;
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
  filter: invert(1);
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.column {
  color: white;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  filter: invert(1);
}

.column:hover {
  background: #091C91; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Snippet for Inverting colores</h1>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
    <div class="column">Column 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```